# module files not downloading for themes

Tags: go, hugo, go-modules

I want to change my site using Hugo. I get stuck with modules. As per documentation (e.g. this theme) I just add `theme = "github.com/nodejh/hugo-theme-mini"` to the config file. It fails like this:

- `WARN ... found no layout file for "HTML" for kind "term": You should ...`
- if I perform `hugo mod vendor` the *directory* structure of the theme seems created in the `_vendor` dir, but there is not a single *file* inside. which explains the "not found" error in my eyes.
- nothing (!) is rendered.

I also have this effect with a couple of other themes (I think[noteworthy](https://github.com/kimcc/hugo-theme-noteworthy) being one of them).

Comment: Following the steps here: https://gohugo.io/getting-started/quick-start/ ... You need to download the theme to your machine. That is done by either using git, or just downloading the project as a zip folder from github. In your site's config file, you should only need to type the theme name, not the github URL.

Comment: as far as i can tell the hugo crows wants to move away from themes as submodules, which i fully understand. the docs of the theme itself explain using the theme as a module as well as a git submodule. see also here: https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/how-to-add-a-theme-using-modules-for-beginners/20665/2 .

Comment: Are you sure there is no file in the _vendor/ theme directory that is created? I don't know what would cause that, aside from a strange file permission issue on your machine. You could try deleting _vendor and trying again. FWIW, using vendor will localize the theme in the project folder. If you want to share the theme across projects, go will download to GOROOT/pkg/mod/github.com/... That happens when you run `go mod init`. If you see the theme files there it should be available.

Comment: I am absolutely sure :) . I have the same problem now with a module that worked flawlessly before. this is such a weird blackbox-system, I really dislike it (although if it works it's like a billion times better than git submodules ). Right now I *think* it has to do with the wrapping that hugo does around go ... I am really lost, super unpredictable.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set up a clean project

```
hugo new site testModules
cd testModules
```

and enable Hugo modules

```
hugo mod init randomName`
```

2. Paste the following lines in `config.toml`:

```ini
baseURL = "http://example.org/"
title = "Hugo Modules Test"

[module]
[[module.imports]]
   path = "github.com/nodejh/hugo-theme-mini"
```

3. Start Hugo

```bash
hugo serve -D
```

Done!
The content of `github.com/nodejh/hugo-theme-mini"` will be downloaded and used as theme.

See the [theme's documentation](https://github.com/nodejh/hugo-theme-mini#2-getting-started) to add content

---

Optional:

```
hugo mod vendor
```

will make the content of the remote repo available in the `_vendor` folder.
(Surprisingly the content of `exampleSite` was not downloaded during the quick test I made)

Comment: For me it doesn't download the themes at all, Hugo just complains that it can't find them... `Error: command error: failed to load modules: module "github.com/vjeantet/hugo-theme-docdock" not found in ".../testModules/themes/github.com/vjeantet/hugo-theme-docdock";`